# Write on CSV file every 10 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am writing a code that should update an empty .csv file with rows containing two columns every 10 seconds. One column containing an integer that indicates time e.g. [0,10,20,30 etc.] with an increase of 10 each time the `initial_time = initial_time + 10` is called (the reason for this is to denote time in 10 seconds intervals for plotting purposes later on), and the second column holding integer contents from count which is constantly updated in a `while(True)` loop.

I cannot use `sleep` function because I need a program to run without a halt, and I'm curious if there is a way of doing so without the use of the threading module.

This is the general code format:

```
import cv2
import csv

c = open('test.csv', 'w', newline='')
collect_data = csv.writer(c, delimiter=',')

count = 0
initial_time = 0

def data_collection():
    global initial_time
    collect_data.writerow([initial_time, count])
    initial_time = initial_time + 10

def other_functions():

while(True):
    other_functions()

    data_collecion()

    for () in something:

    conditions here 

        if(condition):
            count=count+1
    
        more_functions()
        key=cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key==27:
        break

c.close()
```

Comment: You will need to use the `time` module to monitor elapsed time yourself.  Also, the file  will not always be updated on every write.  Typically file output is buffered until the buffer size is exceeded, or the file buffer is flushed, or the file is closed.   That is why you see a bunch of lines after you close and open it.

Comment: Where does the variable `count` come from? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: ```count``` is declared at the beginning of the code holding a value of 0. it then gradually increases ```count=count+1``` in ```for``` loop that has been nested inside a ```while``` loop every time an object passes through the detect line.

Comment: You're going to need to edit your question and provide runnable code the reproduces the problem (for anyone to be able to provide you with a real answer).

Comment: Just made an edit with a basic code format, please do let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Since (apparently) you want to do concurrent processing, I think you are going to need to use threads to do it — in this case specifically instances of the [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) subclass.

Comment: The main reason I want to avoid the threading approach is that it will result in the output being 'unreproducible' and what I want to do instead is use sequential computing so that everything occurs in a reproducible sequence.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 - Create a variable to hold the time; Ex: var **initial_time**;
- 2 - Create a function that write inside the CSV file;
- 3 - Compare the currenttime (now()) with the variable created at step 1: **initial_time**;
- 4 - If had passed 10 seconds:
- 4.1 - Set the new time: i + 10;
- 4.2 - Create a thread to run the function of step 2 to write inside the csv;

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please expand further on the 3rd step mentioned above?